# Bayes Classifier with $2$ Normal Random Variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> For Class $1$ cases, $x$ will be an observation from a normal
>   distribution having a mean of $0$ and a standard deviation of $1$, and
>   for Class $2$ cases, $x$ will be an observation from a normal
>   distribution having a mean of $0$ and a standard deviation of $2$. If
>   Class $1$ cases are just as likely to be observed as Class $2$ cases,
>   for what values of $x$ will a Bayes classifier predict Class $1$? Give
>   the Bayes error rate for the Bayes classifier.

My understanding is that I need to set $\pi_1\cdot f_1(x) \gt \pi_2 \cdot f_2(x)$. Then

$$\begin{align*}
\pi_1\cdot f_1(x) \gt \pi_2 \cdot f_2(x)
& \iff \frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} \gt \frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{8\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{8}}\\\\
& \iff \frac{\sqrt{8\pi}}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \gt \frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{8}}}{e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}}\\\\
& \iff 2 \gt e^{\frac{3x^2}{8}}\\\\
& \iff ln(2) \gt \frac{3x^2}{8} \\\\
& \iff \frac{8}{3}ln(2) \gt x^2
\end{align*}$$

So $$x\in(-1.36,1.36)$$

Would the error rate just be the probability of being outside of this interval if $X\sim N(0,1)$? In which case, I get from a normal table an error rate of $2\cdot0.0869 = 0.1738$

**Edit:**

Would the Bayes error rate be

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2}(P(\vert N_1 \vert) \gt 1.36+P(\vert N_2 \vert) \lt 1.36)
& =\frac{1}{2}(0.1738 + 0.503355) \\
&=.3387\\
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation of the Bayes Classifier is correct; i.e. the Bayes Classifier is given to be

\begin{align*}
C(x) = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{ if } |x| < \sqrt{\frac83 \log(2)}, \\
0 & \text{else.}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

The Bayes error is then defined to be the probability that the classifier is wrong. Letting $I(X)$ denote the true (unobserved) class of a sample $X$ this is the probability

\begin{align*}
E & = \mathbf{P}\left[ C(X) \neq I(X)\right] \\
& = \mathbf{P}\left[ C(X) \neq I(X) \, | \, I(X) = 1 \right] \mathbf{P}[I(X) = 1] + 
\mathbf{P}\left[ C(X) \neq I(X) \, | \, I(X) = 2 \right] \mathbf{P}[I(X) = 2] \\
& = \frac12 \big( \mathbf{P}\left[ C(X) =2 \, | \, I(X) = 1 \right] + \mathbf{P}\left[ C(X) =1 \, | \, I(X) = 1 \right] \big)
\end{align*}
Letting $N_1 \sim N(0,1)$ and $N_2 \sim N(0,4)$ and $\alpha = \sqrt{\frac83 \log(2)} \sim1.36$, then the above probabilities are
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{P} \left[ C(X) = 2 \, | \, I(X) = 1\right] & = \mathbf{P}\left[ \, |N_1| > \alpha \right]\\
\mathbf{P} \left[ C(X) = 1 \, | \, I(X) = 2\right] & = \mathbf{P}\left[ \, |N_2| \leq \alpha \right]
\end{align*}
Denoting $\Phi$ for the CDF of the standard normal distribution we have
\begin{align*}
E & = \frac12 \big( \mathbf{P}\left[ \, |N_1| > \alpha \right] + \mathbf{P}\left[ \, |N_2| \leq \alpha \right] \big) \\
& = \frac12 \left( 1 - \left(\Phi(\alpha) - \Phi(-\alpha)\right) + \left(\Phi\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right) - \Phi\left(-\frac{\alpha}{2}\right) \right)\right) \\
& = \frac12 \mathbf P\left[ \, |N_1| \not\in \left( \frac{\alpha}{2}, \alpha\right) \right]
\end{align*}

Note that the distinction to your solution, which is equivalent to $1 - (\Phi(\alpha) - \Phi(-\alpha) )$, is that you do not consider the case of misclassification as class $2$ when the variable is actually class $1$.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to obtain the Bayes error again and edit my answer.

Comment: And did you mean to write $\vert{x}\vert \lt \sqrt{8/3 ln(2)}$?

Comment: Yes, thanks for spotting; correcting now!

Comment: I edited my question if you wouldn't mind verifying my calculations.

Comment: I was going to. Thanks for the help!